# Can gaming on my MacBook Pro cause harm?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon, games

I have MacBook Pro M1 16", 1TB variant. I have installed Parallels on it and play Dying Light and other games on it three to four hours daily.

My Mac gets hot but till now not that much.

I am wondering if gaming can cause harm to my Mac, especially cause the battery to age.

Should I be worried and stop gaming on it?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing specific temperatures (and specific designs). I wouldn't worry about the battery. I have had an LCD display cable separating and failing around areas of high temperature though; this resulted in ~ 1" vertical strip of the screen display becoming corrupted.

Answer (score 3):

Gaming on your MacBook Pro is not a problem. Those machines are made to be used with "professional users" in mind. This means high load, for example for pro video editing or 3D modeling, all of which may stress both CPU and GPU. If the machine does become too hot, it will reduce performance to compensate. It's unlikely to affect the battery life, either.

My old MacBook Pro was my prime (non-console) gaming machine for years.